# How can I get the Minecraft class loader?

Tags: java, classloader, minecraft

I'm loading an agent to Minecraft JVM and when I get all the loaded classes from the instrumentation, most of them are not there. My code looks like

```java
Class.forName("net.minecraft.client.Minecraft");
```

and I get a ClassNotFoundException. I think it is because most of the Minecraft classes are loaded in a different ClassLoader. Any idea of how can I get this ClassLoader?

Comment: yeah, makes sense, when i look at all the loaded classes more of them have names like abc dss, probably they are obfuscated, can i deobfuscate them?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but

Minecraft is obfuscated You need to use the obfuscated names for this to work

in Minecraft 1.8.9 net.minecraft.client.Minecraft's obfuscated name is ave so you need to use:

```
Class.forName("ave");
```

instead of

```
Class.forName("net.minecraft.client.Minecraft");
```

use [MCPMappingViewer](https://github.com/bspkrs/MCPMappingViewer) to find out what the obfuscated names are :)